# Get Latest Version of library on Github

Tags: github

Folks, I am using the AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar in my app and there are newer features commited by another user here:

https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar/pull/27/commits

however I cannot get the latest version with those changes, does the author of the first version needs to approve and compile a new version and published on github??

thanks,

Comment: If you plan on becoming a regular contributor to this repository then you might want to consider installing Git on your computer.  That being said, you _can_ get the source code for this project directly from [the site here](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar?files=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the fork directly and download the changes made by this user from his fork (In this specific scenario, this is the link you would go to: https://github.com/mystudylife/discreteSeekBar).

Note that these changes have probably not yet been checked by the main repo's organizer and therefore should be used with caution.